# NullReferenceException but during debug i have an object?

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to figure out why my code throws a null reference exception.

I am trying to add an object to a list. The object can be one of 4 types i have all the definitions after the code in question. This code is in a button click handler for the 4 picture boxes in the select case statement

Below is the code in question

```
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim a_component As Object = Nothing

    Select Case (p.Name)
        Case TranspositorPictureBox.Name
            Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
            count = TNumericUpDown.Value
            a_component = New Transpositor(tempTranspositorDivert)
        Case ZonePictureBox.Name
            count = ZNumericUpDown.Value
            a_component = New Zone()
        Case InductionPictureBox.Name
            count = IndNumericUpDown.Value
            a_component = New Induction()
        Case InclinePictureBox.Name
            count = IncNumericUpDown.Value
            a_component = New Incline()
    End Select

    For i = 1 To count
        Dim newPic As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        newPic.Image = p.Image
        newPic.Size = p.Size
        newPic.SizeMode = p.SizeMode

        sys.Add(a_component)

        LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.Add(newPic)
    Next
```

here are the class definitions. the variable sys is of type TranSorter

```
Public Class TranSorter
Public width As Integer
Public components As List(Of Object)

Public Sub New(ByVal the_width As Integer)
    Me.width = the_width
    Me.components = New List(Of Object)
End Sub

Public Sub Add(ByVal next_component As Object)
    Me.components.Add(next_component)
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Transpositor
Public length As Integer
Public divert As Object

Public Sub New(ByVal a_divert As Object)
    Me.divert = a_divert
    Me.length = ComponentLengths.TranspositorLength
    Form1.Transpositors += 1
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Zone
Public length As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Me.length = ComponentLengths.ZoneLength
    Form1.Microzones += 1
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Induction
Public length As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Me.length = ComponentLengths.InductionLength
    Form1.Inductions += 1
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Incline
Public length As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Me.length = ComponentLengths.InclineLength
    Form1.Inclines += 1
End Sub
End Class
```

the sys.add line is throwing the exception. here is the code I initialize sys in

```
Dim sys As TranSorter

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

sys = New TranSorter(temp_width)
```

Comment: In every constructor except the one for the class Transorter you reference an object variable named Form1. Where do you get this variable initialized?

Comment: Form1 is the underlying form, it is initialized through the designer.

Comment: Try to move all of your Form1 operation outside the class constructors and inside the Button1_Click handler

Comment: just tried. The form1 operations don't seem to be the ones throwing the exception. is there something wrong with my Add function?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Do you have initialized the `sys` variable? Could you show the code that declares and initializes this variable?

Comment: sys.Add(a_component)
in the for loop

I tried to add a picture but my reputation is too low:(

Comment: Dim sys As TranSorter

then in Form1_Load i have

    sys = New TranSorter(temp_width)

Comment: Try to set breakpoints on the Form1_Load method and on the ssy.Add Line. Check if the Form_Load executes and/or if sys is Nothing.

Comment: I've removed the VB6 and VBA tags, neither of whihc apply to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should not throw any exception unless the sys is Nothing.
This could be if the Form_Load event, where do you initialize the sys var, doesn't execute. 
You can easily check this situation simply setting a breakpoint on the line

```
 sys = New TranSorter(temp_width)
```

then put another breakpoint on the

```
 sys.Add(a_component)
```

line and check if the sys var is nothing

Comment: turnes out in my form_load function above it's not handling anything so it is never called and sys is never initialized

Answer (score 1):

I suspect for some reason your p.Name does not equal one of the four cases you check for in your If clause. I would recommend considering adding a blanket Else clause and/or checking if a_component is nothing before adding it as an extra precaution.

```
Select Case (p.Name)
    Case TranspositorPictureBox.Name
        Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
        count = TNumericUpDown.Value
        a_component = New Transpositor(tempTranspositorDivert)
    Case ZonePictureBox.Name
        count = ZNumericUpDown.Value
        a_component = New Zone()
    Case InductionPictureBox.Name
        count = IndNumericUpDown.Value
        a_component = New Induction()
    Case InclinePictureBox.Name
        count = IncNumericUpDown.Value
        a_component = New Incline()
    Case Else
        Exit Sub ' Function/etc
End Select

if a_component IsNot Nothing Then
  For i = 1 To count
    Dim newPic As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
    newPic.Image = p.Image
    newPic.Size = p.Size
    newPic.SizeMode = p.SizeMode

    sys.Add(a_component)

    LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.Add(newPic)
  Next
End If
```

Comment: i checked with the debugger and it's always getting the correct value. 

I added the else clause anyway to be safe. But it is still throwing the exception

at the time the exception is thrown a_component is assigned a value and a correct one

Comment: Is it possible that sys is not yet set (if you have a race condition in release mode with the form load)? Try adding a check for `If sys IsNot Nothing`

Comment: now I just need to figure out why sys is nothing?

Comment: How are you calling the code in question? Is it on form init or from an external form before a form.show? That could happen before form load where you are setting up the sys variable.